# Script to select objects of the same width & height (Adobe Illustrator)

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to make a script that can select objects of the same dimensions as the selected object.

So far I have this, which doesn't throw up any errors but it also doesn't work. Can anyone help me fix this? I'm new to scripting in Illustrator so I'm not even sure how to check if it's getting the width/height from the currently selected object. Thanks very much!

```
var docRef=app.activeDocument;

var objWidth = app.selection[0].width;
var objHeight = app.selection[0].height;

var selectionArray = 0;
var str = 0;

var items = docRef.pageItems;
var n = items.length;

for ( i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
{
    var item = items[i];
    if ( item.width == objWidth
    && item.height == objHeight )
    {
        selectionArray [ selectionArray.length ] = item;
    }
}
```

Comment: `selectionArray [ selectionArray.length ] = item;` it works, but it looks weird and probably is not very efficient. Usually if you want to add an element to an array you can use the `push()` method: `selectionArray.push(item);`

Comment: So, did you get an answer?

Comment: Downvoted since there is no feedback from OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the line:

```
var selectionArray = 0;
```

with:

```
var selectionArray = [];
```

And the array will be created fine.

But what do you want to do with this array? If you want to select all the items of this array you have to add at the end of the code this line:

```
app.selection = selectionArray;
```

---

If you want to check a value in order to debug your code you can use the `alert` function. For example:

```
alert('width = ' + objWidth);
```

It will show the window with given text (that contains the value):

[image]